# A function which is continuous in one variable and measurable in other is jointly measurable

Tags: real-analysis, measure-theory

Please help me to prove the following;

> Let $ \ f:[0,1]^2\longrightarrow\mathbb{R}$ be such that:
>
> (i) $\ f(x,\cdot)$ is measurable for each fixed $x\in[0,1]$;
>
> (ii) $\ f(\cdot,y)$ is continuous for each fixed $y\in[0,1]$.
>
> Show that $\ f$ is measurable.

Comment: Can you share what you've tried, and explain what you're having trouble with?

Comment: http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/659305/measurable-function-which-is-continuous-on-one-variable-and-measurable-in-other

This is what I have. But it seems incorrect.

Comment: See [here](http://books.google.at/books?id=4hIq6ExH7NoC&pg=PA153&lpg=PA153&dq=aliprantis+border+infinite+dimensional+analysis+caratheodory+function&source=bl&ots=p9uOVuk3GB&sig=AsBUvp9GYaqOA2yFHfS_0RVLVEU&hl=en&sa=X&ei=4pbuUpeqDMjVsgawxoGABw&ved=0CD8Q6AEwAg#v=onepage&q&f=false).

Comment: The question that this question is a duplicate of has since been deleted; please reopen.

Comment: Regarding the answers, it seems that we only need left/right continuity of $f(\cdot, y)$.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Suppose $f(x, y)$ is continuous in $x$ and measurable in $y$. Let $f_n: \mathbb{R}^2 \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ be defined by $f_n(x, y) = f(m/n, y)$ where $m, n$ are integers $n \geq 1$ and such that $(m-1)/n \leq x < m/n$. Then $f_n$'s are all measurable. Now observe that, since $f$ is continuous in $x$, for fixed $(x, y)$, as $n \rightarrow \infty$, $f_n(x, y) \rightarrow f(x, y)$.

Comment: One question, is the measurabilty here (because the source of the question doesn't specify) is under Borel measure or Lebesgue measure?

Comment: Doesn't matter which one. Both classes are closed under pointwise limits.

Answer (score 6):

This sort of problem frequently boils down to approximating over simple functions of intervals.

In this 
problem, one approach is as follows: Let $\eta_n(t) = {\lfloor n t \rfloor \over n}$. Then for $k \in \mathbb{Z}$, we have $\eta_n(t) = {k \over n}$ **iff** $t \in [ k, k+ { 1 \over n})$. Then we can 'approximate' $f$ by $f(\eta_n(x),y)$ and use the facts that $\eta_n$ is constant over $[ k, k+ { 1 \over n})$ and $\lim_n \eta_n(t) = t$.

Let $\phi_n(x,t) = f(\eta_n(x),y) = \sum_{k \in \mathbb{Z}} 1_{[ k, k+ { 1 \over n})} (x) f({k \over n}, y)$. Since $(x,y) \mapsto 1_{[ k, k+ { 1 \over n})} (x)$ and $(x,y) \mapsto f({k \over n}, y)$ are measurable, we see that the $\phi_n$ are measurable.

Continuity gives $\phi_n(x,y) \to f(x,y)$, hence $f$ is measurable.